# Why didn't Chris didn't feel shocked when Rheya came back for a second time?

Tags: plot-explanation, solaris

In *Solaris* (2002), Chris feels shocked when Rheya appeared on the bed beside him. So he sends her away by releasing her into space using a space probe here, because she is a duplicate of Rheya:

[image]
[image]

But when she appears a second time, he was not surprised and he was comfortable with her coming back. Why?

*she is lying on him here*
[image]